# SSH.NET Library Installation in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, libraries

I would like to install the following library in Visual Studio 2010:
https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET
And I really don't know how I'm supposed to do.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You have to download the source code and compile it into a DLL in [**Visual Studio 2017**](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/), then you can [**add a reference**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.100).aspx) (see _To add a reference in Visual Basic_) to the DLL in your Visual Studio 2010 project.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can install the nuget package manager if you don't yet have in your VS 2010. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/install-nuget) will help you install nuget package manager.

2) After you have nuget manager then you can right click on your project in visual studio, click 'Manage Nuget Packages' and in the browse window that appears search for 'SSH.Net', once the package is listed click on install option to install the package with your project.